# How to serv static file from another domain with NGINX?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have to host `fooz.com` and `barz.com`. I want to serv static file from foo.com for bar.com.
Example http://bar.com/feeds/news.xml should return a file which is saved on foo.com server. So for this I use:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name barz.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    }

    location =/feeds/news.xml {
        proxy_pass http://fooz.com;
    }
}
```

With this setup I get error from nginx:

```
421 Misdirected Request
```